# Chart Range Changes When New Column Pasted in

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel sheet with a chart on it. The data range for this chart is

```
='Sheet A'!$A$1:$N$4,'Sheet A'!$A$7:$N$10
```

This works fine, however every month I add new data to the sheet. I do this by pasting the data into Row A, and shifting the existing data to the right.

When I do this, the chart updates to

```
='Sheet A'!$B$1:$O$4,'Sheet A'!$B$7:$O$10
```

I'd like to have the chart fixed to look at the A-N range, even when I paste in new data. As far as I was aware, the `$` symbol should do this. Do I need to do something else to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

`$` works with autofill of formulas only, your described story is the expected behaviour of Excel, you can't really change it.

As a workaround, either:

- you can keep column A blank, paste each month new data starting from column B, but keep data range starting from column A, this way you'll have an empty column / series in you data, but range updates correctly
- when update your data:

  1. at first insert a new column before column B
  2. copy (not move!) column A content to column B
  3. overwrite column A with new data
- use a macro to automatically update data range

Answer (score 0):

The insertion of a new column A makes Excel adjust the ranges, and there is no setting to get that from happening. It is a well known limitation; the usual adjustment that most people do is:

1. Copy column A and insert the copy *between* A and B. Inserting it *inside* the current range of the chart makes the chart extend by one column. You will now see two copies of the data from A.
2. paste your new data over the existing column A.

You should generally get used to work this way, as it avoids many issues with formulas in Excel - also when you work with rows, always copy the last row and insert the copy *before* the original, and then overwrite the last line's data. That keeps all formulas active for the new row too.